# MAGNOLIA CMS - When using cmsu:simpleSearch and cmsu:searchResultSnippet links are not displayed properly and can't convert date into readable format

Tags: jsp, magnolia

**When using cmsu:simpleSearch and cmsu:searchResultSnippet links are not displayed properly.**

This is my code:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.contentSearchPattern}">
    <h1>xx results for "${fn:escapeXml(param.contentSearchPattern)}"</h1>
    <ol>
        <cmsu:simpleSearch query="${param.contentSearchPattern}" var="results" startLevel="1" />
        <c:if test="${empty results}">
            <p>No results</p>
        </c:if>
        <c:forEach var="node" items="${results}">
            <li>
                <h2><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${node.handle}.html">${node.title}</a></h2>
                <p class="pageResultUrl">drintranet-testdev${node.handle}.html</p>
                <p><cmsu:searchResultSnippet query="${param.contentSearchPattern}" page="${node}" chars="120"/></p>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ol>
</c:if>
```

So let's say I have a page matching the search pattern, it'll display the snippet correctly if this is text only. But if the text matching the pattern is a link it will display the snippet such as "" with  not being linked anymore.

I would like to be able to keep the same format. ie. if a text is also a link, display the text with the link.

---

**Also, when using cmsu:simpleSearch and cmsu:searchResultSnippet I want to display the date the page/article was created.**

Here is the code:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.contentSearchPattern}">
    <h1>xx results for "${fn:escapeXml(param.contentSearchPattern)}"</h1>
    <ol>
        <cmsu:simpleSearch query="${param.contentSearchPattern}" var="results" startLevel="1" />
        <c:if test="${empty results}">
            <p>No results</p>
        </c:if>
        <c:forEach var="node" items="${results}">
            <li>
                <h2><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${node.handle}.html">${node.title}</a></h2>
                <p class="pageResultUrl">drintranet-testdev${node.handle}.html</p>
                <p><cmsu:searchResultSnippet query="${fn:escapeXml(param.contentSearchPattern)}" page="${node}" chars="120"/></p>
                <p>Creation Date: ${node.metaData.creationDate}</p>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ol>
</c:if>
```

But it returns for the Creation Date line:

> Creation Date:
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1307354223649,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+01:00",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=157,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=57,SECOND=3,MILLISECOND=649,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]

I'm trying to convert this date into a human readable format using this type of code:

```
  <cms:ifNotEmpty nodeDataName="date">
    <cms:out nodeDataName="date" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" var="eventDate"/>
  </cms:ifNotEmpty>
```

But this is not working as pageDate is not a nodeDataName I assume, any idea how to get this right?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead `<p>Creation Date: ${node.metaData.creationDate.time}</p>`, but I don't know if that will work. `node.metaData.creationDate` is of type java.util.Calendar, and not `java.util.Date`. 
Do the conversion from Calendar to Date, first.

Comment: thanks for answering. sorry for not being able to check your answer though, this question is pretty old & I'm now working on other things. A.

Answer (score 0):

SearchResultSnippetTag neuters the HTML deliberately, as it doesn't want to leave you in the position of having displayed an <a> tag that's in the first 120 characters without also displaying the </a> tag (which may or may not be in the first 120 characters). In order to get this to work the way you'd like, you'd need to rewrite that class, tracking all of the tags that get opened in that first 120 characters so that you can make sure the corresponding close tag gets output as well.

For the date issue, per [this page](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Display+latest+modification+date) on the wiki, it looks like you should be able to use the <cms:out> tag like this:

<cms:out nodeDataName="mgnl:creationdate" contentNodeName="MetaData" />